# What is the technical reason an array of interfaces can't be indexed into unless the index is constant?

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog, vivado, hdl

I'm curious as to why an array of interfaces can't be indexed into unless the index is constant. Specifically I'm curious as to the case where a for loop is used, because a for loop elaborates into an expanded piece of code, i.e. the index is in fact constant.

I'm presuming it just the order in the compile/build process that things get elaborated that causes this.

Example:

```
module some_module(
  my_intf.modport intf,
  input logic clk
);

    integer index = 0;

    always@(posedge clk) begin

       .....

        for (index = 0; index < 4; index = index + 1) begin
               if(intf[index].net) begin
                   //logic
               end
        end

        .....

    end //always
endmodule //some_module
```

Should be equivalent to:

```
module some_module(
  my_intf.modport intf,
  input logic clk
);

    always@(posedge clk) begin

       .....
           if(intf[0].net) begin
                   //logic
           end
           if(intf[1].net) begin
                   //logic
           end
           if(intf[2].net) begin
                   //logic
           end
           if(intf[3].net) begin
                   //logic
           end

        .....

    end //always
endmodule //some_module
```

For context: I'm using Vivado as my toolchain and receive a Vivado simulator error of:

> ERROR: [VRFC 10-2951] "index" is not constant

Manually unpacking the `for` loop works, as expected. (Which is what leads me to believe that the `for` loop is not unpacked until sometime later in the compile/build process). When the `for` loop is used, I get a Vivado simulator error,

Comment: I can't post full code for confidentiality reasons, but its effectively identical as to what is seen above.  Manually unpacking the for loop works, as expected. (Which is what leads me to believe that the for loop is not unpacked until sometime later in the compile/build process). When the for loop is used I get a Vivado simulator error of "ERROR: [VRFC 10-2951] "index" is not a constant".

Comment: Add the error message to your question instead of in the comments.  You don't need to post confidential code, but you can post code that we can try that reproduces the problem.  See my answer below.

Comment: Did my answer work for you in Vivado?

Comment: Since you are a new user: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the LRM does not allow it; it's not a *true* array.

*True* arrays are groups of variables with identical data types. An individual index selection of an array is guaranteed to have the same data type regardless of which index value is being selected.

Module and interface instances are namespaces that get elaborated/flattened as part of the compilation process. The index `intf[0]` etc. becomes part of the hierarchical path name as if you had manually entered `intf_0`. Parameterization, bind. and port collapsing can have different effects on each instance so that they are no longer identical. Although there are a number of cases where it would not make a difference, the LRM has strict rules about indexing into instances using constants.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `generate` construct to access indexes of an array of interfaces.  Here is a minimal example that compiles without errors with multiple simulators on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/VwjW):

```
interface my_intf;
    logic net;
endinterface

module some_module(
  my_intf intf [4],
  input logic clk
);

    for (genvar index = 0; index < 4; index = index + 1) begin
        always @(posedge clk) begin
            if (intf[index].net) begin
                //logic
            end
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 27. *Generate constructs*